# How to make resume from suspend work properly on Wayland + Nvidia?

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, suspend, wayland

Using Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome and a 20 series Nvidia card with the proprietary driver. Resuming from suspend on a Wayland session breaks the screen (almost entirely black with some few visible blacks, even though commands still work, so I can just reboot). This is a common issue with Nvidia cards from what I've seen, and the Arch wiki even describes a [workaround](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA/Tips_and_tricks#Driver_persistence), but Ubuntu doesn't handle mkinitcpio the same way Arch does, so I am note sure how to reproduce the steps described there on here. I've also tried [this method](https://github.com/robswc/ubuntu-22-nvidia-suspend-fix-script) specific for Ubuntu which is basically a shell script can I still can't make it work properly. This is the only issue preventing me from switching to Wayland entirely at this point.

Comment: I got it to work (ryzen5) installing propietary drivers (we are not supposed to with amdgpu chips, even though there is a seperate video gpu that Ubuntu apparently does not want to use , though right click on bottom bar apps has the option to use it.  - I am not a gamer so I do not bother.), but then selecting the bottom one, which was open source (1.55?) in software, additional drivers. right now all the prop. ones are greyed out and the bottom one , selected but locked in (will not toggle) says 'continue using a manually installed drivers'. what the heck , it works

Comment: . Wayland is being used. 'ps -e | grep tty'

Comment: I'm using Nvidia...